# KeyError because sometimes key is not present

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
if house["condition"]["#text"] is str:
    condition = ["condition"]["#text"]
else:
    condition = "bananas"
```

In the dict house["condition"], sometimes the key #text is not even in the dict.

Why do I get `KeyError: #text`, if there is a conditional? I also tried `is not KeyError` but didn't manage to get it working.

Comment: You want to test `if "#text" in house["Condition"]:` before you try to access `house["condition"]["#text"]`.  You can also do `house["condition"].get("#text")`, which will return `None` if `#text` is not an existing key.  So you can simply replace the first line of your code with `if house["condition"].get("#text") is str:`

Comment: Is `["state"]["#text"]` supposed to be `house["state"]["#text"]`?

Comment: `is str` is not the way to test the type of the value. That should be `isinstance(..., str)`

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty sure the `is str` was a failed attempt to check if the key exists.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test:

```
if "#text" in house["Condition"]:
```

before you try to access `house["condition"]["#text"]`. You can also use `get()`, which will return None if `#text` is not an existing key. So you can simply replace the first line of your code with:

```
if house["condition"].get("#text") is str:
```

I assume that you are meaning to test if the resulting value for the key is a string.  To do that, you instead should do:

```
if isinstance(house["condition"].get("#text"), str):
```

Comment: I thought it was working, and it did for those which had no key, but it also made all the others "bananas"

Comment: @PauloAlves - yes.  I hope the second part of my answer addresses that.